# Can't select the siblings of an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings

I've tried seemingly every combination of .siblings, .parents().siblings, with and without $(this). or just 'this', and I can't for the life of me get jquery to select the sibling of an element that's clicked on.

Here's the relevant html:

```
<div class='showButton'>
      <p class='opener'>Get The Code</p>
      <code class='hideShow'>
```

Here's the relevant jquery that i've gotten to work, but it selects and opens every single instance of that class on the page:

```
$('.opener').click( () => {
if(clickCount == 0){
    $('.hideShow').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.hideShow').css('position', 'static');
```

Any form of $(this), $(this > '.hideShow'), $(this).siblings(), or $(this).parents('.showButton').siblings() seems to have zero effect, whether it's my design or from the internet. The JS you see above is literally the only thing that will affect the page in any way.

I have multiple of these .opener classes on the page, and I'd just like to change the CSS on the sibling of the clicked element. Am I going about this the wrong way?

edit: It currently selects every instance of the class, as that's the only thing that works in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.hideShow')` will match all `.hideShow`, instead you need to use `this` and find the `.hideShow` within its parent.

```js
$('.opener').click(function(e) {
  const hideShow = $(e.currentTarget).parent().find('.hideShow');
  hideShow.css('visibility', 'visible');
  hideShow.css('position', 'static');
});
```

```css
.hideShow {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='showButton'>
  <p class='opener'>Get The Code</p>
  <code class='hideShow'>Code</code>
</div>

<div class='showButton'>
  <p class='opener'>Get The Code</p>
  <code class='hideShow'>Code</code>
</div>

<div class='showButton'>
  <p class='opener'>Get The Code</p>
  <code class='hideShow'>Code</code>
</div>
```

Comment: Same results as before... But that's what I was saying: any form of 'this' in the code renders it completely useless. It registers that theres a click event, posts things to the console if i console.log(), but anything with any sort of 'this' attached becomes ignored.

Comment: okay, then you can use `event.currentTarget`, thus avoiding `this`. Please check now

Comment: That's perfect!! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

When `opener` element click you need to first find the parent, for that you can use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and after that, you find the `hideShow` element and apply your CSS over that.

Try below code-

```js
$('.opener').click(function() {
  $('.hideShow').hide()
  const hideShow = $(this).closest('.showButton').find('.hideShow').show();
});
```

```css
.hideShow {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class='showButton'>
  <p class='opener'>Get The Code</p>
  <code class='hideShow'>Code</code>
</div>

<div class='showButton'>
  <p class='opener'>Get The Code</p>
  <code class='hideShow'>Code</code>
</div>

<div class='showButton'>
  <p class='opener'>Get The Code</p>
  <code class='hideShow'>Code</code>
</div>
```

Comment: This had some sort of effect, but not quite right. It made the contents of the .hideShow class show up in only the clicked one, but every other .hideShow opened to full size as well, it just didn't have it's content.

Comment: Try again. I have updated my answer. Also, don't use `visibilty` style to hide because its just hidden the element's content not the size of element. @HeyItsGwen

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below approach. Use `next()` to select the next element or `prev()` to select the previous element. And use normal function then arrow function to bind the `this` keyword.

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            let clickCount = 0;
            $('.opener').click(function() {
                if (clickCount == 0) {
                    $(this).next().css('visibility', 'visible');
                    $(this).next().css('position', 'static');
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class='showButton'>
        <p class='opener'>Get The Code</p>
        <code class='hideShow' style="visibility: hidden;">Code tag</code>
    </div>
```